# How to hide urlbar on SenchaTouch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

The Javascript function

```
window.scrollTo(0,1);
```

doesn't seem to have any effect on SenchaTouch2
I don't know where but it may be blocked by the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your Sencha Touch app outer-most component takes up all space (width & height) available of your device screen. Scrolling actually means scrolling up & down in your **element**, not the window.

That why `window.scrollTo(x,y)` is not blocked but has no visible effects.

Comment: Is it hard to put window's absolute width and height calculated during dom loading, or refresh when orientation changes, that would enable window.scroll then